# Consolidation of MSSQL Databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to bring databases from different instance/server (MSSQL 2008 R2) to single MSSQL Server/Instance.

Existing databases have cross references/linked server used in code, so when I will simply be restoring databases from source to consolidated Target Instance.

would they be get created successfully irrespective of any cross databases dependencies or linked server references ?
Linked server will be created as a next task to make databases fully functional.

I have tried creating database copies on target and backup restore from source is failing due to external references

Comment: The restore should work even without the external references present.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I have tried that and later created external references (linked server / dependent db's) , its failing ..am I missing any step

Comment: Are you just using `RESTORE`?  Scripts that reference external resources not yet created will fail.

Comment: Yes I am using RESTORE , Is there anyways where external references will be ignored and databases can be create successfully with all objects

Comment: What errors are you getting during the `RESTORE`?  I haven't seen such an issue.

Comment: Thanks Dan ! I achieved my purpose by copying/attaching mdf/ldf/ndf from source to target and database is up without bothering about any external references , I can create external reference now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dan ! I achieved my purpose by copying/attaching mdf/ldf/ndf from source to target and database is up without bothering about any external references , I can create external reference now.